# filter days of week createDateRangeArray

Tags: php, cakephp, date-range

I have this function to generate an array of dates between a range. I need to modify it so that it will accept another paramerter if passed with a particular day of the week.

I will then get all the dates for that day within the range. I have not been able to modify. Thanks.

Here is my updated code, it is still add for evey day in the date range even though I am passing in the value of 6. I is probably staring me in the face but I cannot see it.

```
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo,$dateOfWeek=6) {
  // takes two dates formatted as YYYY-MM-DD and creates an
  // inclusive array of the dates between the from and to dates.

  // could test validity of dates here but I'm already doing
  // that in the main script

  $aryRange=array();

  $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
  $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

  if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom) {


    if(!isset($dateOfWeek) || date('w')==$dateOfWeek) //if dateOfWeek not given or same as given
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));

        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo) {
          $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
          array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
  }

  if(count($aryRange)<1){
    return false;
  } else{
    return $aryRange;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
```

by

```
if(date('w',$iDateFrom)==$dateOfWeek)
    array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
```

where `$dateOfWeek` is 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)

Besides, you can rewrite your code to:

```
 while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo) {          
      array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
      $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours, after adding it
 }
```

to avoid repeat of code here (You need not `if` after that)

To add it as optional argument:

```
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo,$dateOfWeek=null){

    if(!isset($dateOfWeek) || date('w')==$dateOfWeek) //if dateOfWeek not given or same as given
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, what would be the best way to do this only if the day is sent to the function, else if not sent, get all the dates dates in the range?

Comment: This does not seem to work. I am passing the valus 6 for Sat abd it still updates for all dates in the range and not Saturadys only.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer (from RiaD) basically nails it.

Just a note: if you want just a specific weekday, there's no need to iterate every weekday.

You could iterate everyday until the first desired weekday, from them on just skip 86400*7 seconds. Much more efficient.